# Turned off HTTP access to my router by mistake

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh

I've disabled ICMP and HTTP access by mistake on my router today and I cant access it anymore :(

The worst part is that the reset button is broken and I can't reset my router to the factory settings.

My router is Huawei HG630 V2 provided by my ISP.. I have SSH access but its like that:

```
login as: admin
admin@192.168.1.1's password:
Server refused to allocate pty
HG520b>
```

no command works except `reboot` on this SSH ..
When I reboot using SSH, it comes online for 3 seconds then goes offline again

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: either take the router apart and fix/replace the reset button or replace the router.

Comment: @Moab - Thank you for the recommendation, however I made what the reset button does using the SSH terminal provided in the router.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it!

So I mentioned in the question that SSH was working but only the `reboot` command worked on the ATP CLI.. However, I've tried a few attempts to discover other commands and the command `restore` worked! It restored my router to factory settings and now I can access my router's web.